# Regex to delete particular tr tag from table in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var tableData = '<tr id=7020934><td>7020934</td><td>anuradha</td><td><a href="#" class="delete">x</a></td></tr><tr id=8736519><td>8736519</td><td>Rohan</td><td><a href="#" class="delete">x</a></td></tr>';
```

I want to delete tr tag with a given id.

I wrote following regex but it is returning false everytime

```
var regex='<tr id=7020934.+?<\/tr>';
alert(/regex/.test(tableData));
```

But if I am using

```
alert(/<tr id=7020934.+?<\/tr>/.test(tableData));
```

i m getting true in alert box.
I am not able to understand the difference between the two approaches.

As my ids are dynamically generated I want to take first approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do

```
var regex=/<tr id=7020934.+?<\/tr>/;
alert(regex.test(tableData));
```

The problem is that anything between `//` is treated as regular expression and not a variable.

If you want to construct a regex based on a variable:

```
var regex = new RegExp(pattern,modifiers)
```

So in your case would be:

```
var regex='<tr id=7020934.+?<\/tr>';
alert(new RegExp(regex).test(tableData));
```

Basically you can think of

```
var regex = /pattern/modifiers;
```

as

```
var regex = new RegExp(pattern,modifiers);
```

Comment: actually i want to do something like

Comment: var regex='<tr id='+$id+'.+?<\/tr>'; that is why i am putting regex in quotes

Comment: But in the 2nd case you say `/variableName/.test...` where `variableName` is not evaluated as a variable but taken as a string. See the updated answer: I think what you're looking for is `RegExp`